# Ng Repeat doesn't show data from array of dates in the web page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng repeat on array of dates doesn't show the data in the web page, notice that when I set direct data into the array without loop it works:
[image]
In this code I'm converting string date to an object then I create array of dates, increasing the date in 1 day in each iteration:

```
         //dates for table
            //convert date to object to allow me do action on it like increase the date in the table
            var startDate = $scope.tripById[0].start_date;
            var dateInNumberFormat = new Date(startDate).getTime();
            //create array for the dates to show it on table, each cell will have 1 extra day
            var day = 1000 * 3600 * 24; //day in miliseconds 1000 * 3600 = hour
            $scope.dates[0] = new Date(dateInNumberFormat + day);
            for(var i = 1; i < daysSum ; i++){
                day = 1000 * 3600 * (i * 24);
                $scope.dates[daysSum] = new Date(dateInNumberFormat + day);
                console.log($scope.dates[daysSum]);
            }
```

here is the ng-repeat:

```
  <table ng-table="usersTable" class="table table-striped" style="text-align: center;">

            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td ng-repeat="date in dates track by $index">{{date}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Why ng repeat on my array doesn't show me the dates in the web page?

Comment: Can you replicate this in a Plunker? Would be much easier to help.

Comment: I'm new to Angular, could be that ng-repat works before the array is ready?

Comment: Need to see more of the code to be able to help.

Comment: @tasseKATT when was trying to write it in Plunker I found that I had a mistake in index, thank you next time I will do it before posting. it's possible to remove the post, it's not informative

Comment: Glad  you found the error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop you put all dates in the same index. Change it as:

```
for(var i = 1; i < daysSum ; i++){
    day = 1000 * 3600 * (i * 24);
    $scope.dates[i] = new Date(dateInNumberFormat + day);
    console.log($scope.dates[i]);
}
```